# Webpack loader error: You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-loader

Once add `react-hot-loader` to Webpack config, the following error will arise.

```sh
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (22:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../../virgin-land/nice-compile-pc/builder/lib/add-react-hot-loader-to-source.js
 * ../../../virgin-land/nice-compile-pc/node_modules/_webpack-string-replacer@0.0.16@webpack-string-replacer/Dist/Loader.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| ]
| 
> @observer
| class FilterBar extends React.Component {
|   constructor(props) {
```

```js
const rules = [
    {
      oneOf: [
        // add this one
        {
          id: 'react-hot-loader',
          test: /\.jsx$/,
          loader: require.resolve('./add-react-hot-loader-to-source')
        },
        {
          id: 'image',
          test: /\.(svg|bmp|gif|png|jpe?g)$/,
          loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            name: '[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
          }
        },
        {
          id: 'js',
          test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
          loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          options: Object.assign({
            cacheDirectory: true
          }, populateFinalBabelConfig(babelConfig))
        },
        {
          id: 'default',
          exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
          loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
          options: {
            name: '[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

The loader `./add-react-hot-loader-to-source` source as below:

```
const PRODUCTION_ENV = 'production';
const EXPORT_DEFAULT_REGEX = /^\s*export\s+default/m;
const EXPORT_DEFAULT_WITH_TRAILING_SPACES_REGEX = /^\s*export\s+default\s+/m;
const DEFAULT_EXPORTED_CLASS_REGEX = /^\s*export\s+default\s+class\s+(.*?)\s+/m;
const DEFAULT_EXPORTED_FUNCTION_REGEX = /^\s*export\s+default\s+function\s+([^(\s]*)\s?\(/m;
const IMPORT_STATEMENT = "import {hot} from 'react-hot-loader/root';\n";
const EXTEND_KEYWORD = 'extends';

/**
 * @param {string} source 
 * @returns {string} A modified source which has the hot reload wrapping 
 */
function AddReactHotLoader(source) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === PRODUCTION_ENV || !source || !EXPORT_DEFAULT_REGEX.exec(source)) {
        return source;
    }
    let newSource = getImportLine() + source;
    const className = getExportDefaultClassName(source);
    const functionName = getExportDefaultFunctionName(source);
    const defaultExportedName = className || functionName;
    console.log('defaultExportedName', defaultExportedName);
    return defaultExportedName ? transformSource(newSource, defaultExportedName) : transformSourceDefault(newSource);
}

/**
 * @param {string} source 
 * @param {string} defaultExportedName The name of the origin default export name
 * that needs to be wrapped in hot reload
 * @returns {string} A source which includes the hot reload wrapper export
 */
function transformSource(source, defaultExportedName) {
    source = source.replace(EXPORT_DEFAULT_WITH_TRAILING_SPACES_REGEX, '');
    source += `\nexport default hot(module)(${defaultExportedName});`;
    console.log('source', source);

    return source;
}

/**
 * @param {string} source 
 * @returns {string} A source which includes the hot reload wrapper export
 */
function transformSourceDefault(source) {
    source = source.replace(EXPORT_DEFAULT_REGEX, 'const reactAppToMakeSuperHot =');
    source += `\nexport default hot(reactAppToMakeSuperHot);`;
    console.log('source', source);

    return source;
}

/**
 * @returns {string} An import statement followed with a line break
 */
function getImportLine() {
    return IMPORT_STATEMENT;
}

/**
 * Returns the default exported class name if exists or an empty string
 * @param {string} source
 * @returns {string} A class name which is exported as default
 */
function getExportDefaultClassName(source) {
    const matches = source.match(DEFAULT_EXPORTED_CLASS_REGEX);
    const hasClassName = matches && matches[1] && matches[1] !== EXTEND_KEYWORD;
    return hasClassName ? matches[1] : '';
}

/**
 * Returns the default exported function name if exists or an empty string
 * @param {string} source
 * @return {string} A function name which is exported as default
 */
function getExportDefaultFunctionName(source) {
    const matches = source.match(DEFAULT_EXPORTED_FUNCTION_REGEX);
    const hasFunctionName = matches && matches[1];
    return hasFunctionName ? matches[1] : '';
}

module.exports = AddReactHotLoader;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, should use `rules` but not `oneOf`.